# Content flow under image CSS

Tags: html, css

Ok I have a background that has a clear area that I have balanced content inside and I want it to slide under the top of the image when the user scrolls it up. I have a jsfiddle with it, excuse my sloppy css I have been trying everything to get this to work. I also have a floating nav bar that it should slide under also.

http://jsfiddle.net/CFFwA/

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html,body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body{
    background-image:url(images/1920w.png);
    background-size:100%;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#E9C9A0;
    z-index:5;
    }

#bod{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(images/1920w.png);
    background-size:100%;
    background-position:center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    left:0;
    z-index:20;
}

#bann{

    width:62.5%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:10;
}


#head{
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:8.5%;
    margin-right:18.75%;
    margin-left:18.75%;
    width:62.5%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:32;
    }

#content{
    padding-top:14%;
    width:62.5%%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index:4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to make your image a separate element with `position:fixed`

**HTML**

```
<img src="/path/to/bg.png" id="body-bg" />
```

**CSS**

```
#body-bg {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

**[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFFwA/1/)**